# char array declaration in C

Tags: c

I have been reading C book by K&R. I came across this words

Character arrays are a special case of initialization; a string may be used instead of the braces and commas notation:

```
char pattern = "ould";
```

is a shorthand for the longer but equivalent

```
char pattern[] = { 'o', 'u', 'l', 'd', '\0' };
```

In this case, the array size is five (four characters plus the terminating '\0').

I coded a simple program to test it as

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char c= "Hello";
    printf("%s",c);
    return 0;
}
```

According to that book there should be no error but it returns an error

```
`cannot convert char * to char`
```

As per my previous knowledge of arrays,the array statement should be like `char *c="Hello";`
  Can you explain the meaning of the words in that book please. Did i Misunderstand the meaning of that words??

Comment: Is there really a line in your book telling " char pattern = "ould"; "  ?

Comment: Yes I just copied and pasted them Here

Comment: Are you really sure ? I think it misses brackets ...

Comment: Page 86 of my copy of K&R (2nd Edition) reads `char pattern[] = "ould";`. If you have a digital copy (you did say you copied and pasted it), it may have been an oversight in the transcription or automated scanning process.

Comment: Yep i now think the same...

Comment: I have a digital copy and it is also 2nd edition. But my page number is 73 in my copy

Comment: At any rate, the book is filled with errors and also very outdated. I wouldn't recommend anyone to read it, particularly not beginners looking for a mean to learn C.

Comment: [K&R errata](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/2ediffs.html).

Comment: @Lundin errors are treated in http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/2ediffs.html other errors come from illicit digital copies of the book

Comment: So @Ludin can you suggest me any other book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's missing two brackets. `char pattern[] = "ould";` will work fine. Time to trash that book !

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
char pattern[] =  "ould" ;
```

Also be careful with :

```
char* pattern = "ould";
```

Please note that with "" you define a const characters array. It is supposed not to change anymore during app execution. If you do:

```
pattern[2] = '9';
```

your app may crash.

Correct is:

```
const char* pattern = "ould";
```

Why is that? Your compiler probably will allocate the "ould" in a protected read only memory block and pattern is just a pointer to it. If you however define :

```
char pattern[] = { 'o', 'u', 'l', 'd', '\0' };
```

It is totally different. It is a modifiable buffer in your local program stack. You can write pattern[2] = '9'; in this case. It is the same as to define char buffer with size 5 and copy text in it. Please read from somewhere else about string initializations and string literals.

Comment: *it should be: {thecode}* that's wrong. It wouldn't fit the context, since the one you've provided is not equivalent to the other.

Comment: Sorry. char pattern[] =  "ould" ; is also Ok.

Comment: The string literal is not `const` h, however it causes undefined behaviour to modify it.